# How do I connect to the Campaign Monitor API?

Tags: php, api

I have somewhat of a knowledge of the PHP coding language and I would like to connect the Campaign Monitor API([Link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/kits/)) with my website, so that when the user enters something into the form on my site it will add it to the database on the Campaign Monitor servers. I found the PHP code example zip file, but it contains like 30 files, and I have no idea where to begin.

Does anyone know of a tutorial anywhere that explains how to connect to the API in a step-by-step manner? The code files by themselves include to much code that I may not need for simply connecting to the database and adding and deleting users, since I only want to give the user the power to add and delete users from the Mailing List.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This actually looks pretty straightforward.  In order to use the API, you simply need to `include()` the `CMBase.php` file that is in that zip file.

Once you've included that file, you can create a `CampaignMonitor` object, and use it to access the API functions.  I took this example out of one of the code files in there:

```
require_once('CMBase.php');

$api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client_id = null;
$campaign_id = null;
$list_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$cm = new CampaignMonitor( $api_key, $client_id, $campaign_id, $list_id );

//This is the actual call to the method, passing email address, name.
$result = $cm->subscriberAdd('joe@notarealdomain.com', 'Joe Smith');
```

You can check the result of the call like this (again taken from their code examples):

```
if($result['Result']['Code'] == 0)
    echo 'Success';
else
    echo 'Error : ' . $result['Result']['Message'];
```

Since you're only interested in adding a deleting users from a mailing list, I think the only two API calls you need to worry about are `subscriberAdd()` and `subscriberUnsubscribe()`:

```
$result = $cm->subscriberAdd('joe@notarealdomain.com', 'Joe Smith');
$result = $cm->subscriberUnsubscribe('joe@notarealdomain.com');
```

Hope that helps.  The example files that are included in that download are all singular examples of an individual API method call, and the files are named in a decent manner, so you should be able to look at any file for an example of the corresponding API method.

Comment: Thank you SO very much! I wish I could give you more than one point for this answer. this is exactly what I need! You rock!

Comment: How would I grab the information from a form instead of the generic joe@notarealdomain.com example? I want to make it dynamic.

Comment: You'll need to learn PHP/HTML and HTTP_POST_VARS etc. to get a the form value. This is a completely different topic - do a google on HTTP_POST_VARS and PHP to find out how.

Comment: Thanks zombat - good explanation. The Campaign Monitor API documentation is technical, and in the code. It explains everything but there's no 'How do I get started' information for PHP AFAIK, but your answer pretty much covered it.